How to extract files with colon in name by Python on Windows?
I'm writing a script for extracting zip/tar files just by Python3 on Windows. it works ok normally, but with some TAR/ZIP files from Linux with colon (":") in filenames, only empty file with names before ":" part was created.
is there some way to compact these files with ":" in name by python on windows?
(e.g. replace ":" with "_" after successfully extract files?)
Here's my testing script code:
import zipfile
import tarfile

uri="/path/to/file.zip"
file = zipfile.ZipFile(uri, 'r')
file.extractall(uri[:-4])

uri="/path/to/file.tar"
file = tarfile.open(uri, 'r')
file.extractall(uri[:-4])


Strange, the documentation suggests that : is replaced with _ on Windows.

"only empty file with names before ":" part was created." You've actually created files with alternate data streams :)

Instead of extracting all files usign extractall() you can iterate over each item, replace invalid character in the filename and then extract them to the desired lovation:
Implementation for ZIP files:
import zipfile
import os
def sanitize_filename(filename)
    return filename.replace(":", "_")
uri = "/path/file.zip"
output_dir = uri[:-4]
with zipfile.ZipFile(uri, 'r') as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = sanitize_filename(member)
        source = zip_file.open(member)
        target = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target), exist_ok=True)
        with open(target, "wb") as target_file:
            target_file.write(source.read())

Implementation for TAR files:
import tarfile
import os
def sanitize_filename(filename):
    return filename.replace(":", "_")
uri = "/path/file.zip"
output_dir = uri[:-4]
with tarfile.open(uri, 'r') as tar_file:
    for member in tar_file.getmembers():
        filename = sanitize_filename(member.name)
        source = tar_file.extractfile(member)
        target = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(target), exist_ok=True)
        if source is not None:
            with open(target, "wb") as target_file:
                target_file.write(source.read())


great and thx, this also solved another problem of the long file/path name on win platform.

zipfile does the suggested conversion automatically. For tarfile you have to provide the errors argument to TarFile, since the normal surrogateescape does not seem to work for you.
